# Automatically Take Picture UIImagePickerController not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

I want to automatically take an image in my application when the camera is presented. I am using SwiftUI and UIImagePickerController for the camera application.

Here is my code for the ImagePicker:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices


class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    ...
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        print("This should print if this method is called but it doesn't print")
        let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        image = uiImage
        isShown = false
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
    
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    @Binding var didTapCapture: Bool
    
    
    @State var pic = true

    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        if pic{
        uiViewController.takePicture() // this doesn't work and no image is found in the "func imagePickerController()" method above
        }

        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
        return ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
    }
    
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        //picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        
        picker.showsCameraControls = false


        return picker
    }
    
    
}
```

From some research I did myself, I think that I need to present the picker before I can take a picture, but I am not sure how to do that? Or I might be headed down the wrong track.

Any help will be appreciated.